# Fargate Applications Logs Streaming to Self-Hosted ELK from Lambda

Tags: devops, amazon-ecs, elastic-stack, aws-fargate, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

APPROACH:
Application Logs [Fargate] --> AWS CloudWatch --> Lambda trigger --> Streaming to Self-Hosted ELK

OBJECTIVE:
To send application logs from CloudWatch to Logstash in every 10seconds.

I just wanted to know,

1. Is above approach valid or implementable?
2. I know how much Lambda will costs, but not able to find out the cost of CloudWatch.
3. Is there any documentation regarding this approach?
4. Is this approach, good for Production?
5. If you have any other solution for streaming application logs to self-hosted ELK stack in AWS, Please tell.

NOTE: Application will be hosted on Fargate in ECS.

Comment: You couldn't find the "Logs" pricing on this page? https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/